# How to access WOrdpress functions from within a class

Tags: php

I am working with Wordpress 3.6 and am building a custom class.

I need some of the Wordpress functionality and settings in my class.

I could add the info I need 1 bit at a time when the class is created, but that is going to require adding new data each time I decide I need to use it.

Is there a way to create a reference or something that will allow me to access the WP functionality and settings from within my class?

Comment: Does your class load in WordPress context?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The class is included and created in a plug-in. ex; include 'myClass.php'; $nc = new myClass();

Comment: Then you should be able to use all Wordpress functions normally...  No extra programming required.  Have you tried / are you experiencing issues?

Comment: No, I didn't. I assumed that a class works in a completely different scope without access. Now, after doing a little testing, I see everything from WP is accessible. Thanks. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: The only time when WP's core functions are not available is when linking to your php files directly. Though this can easily be overcome.

Comment: Is this a PHP thing? Because I know from other languages, you cannot just call functions from outside a class like this. Anyone know where I can read about this in PHP?